# Bump map give no effect on texture in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, bump-mapping

I am using THREE.ImageUtils to load  maps and bumpmaps.The grayscale image of the maps are used as bumpmaps .on adding bump maps it doesnt gives any effect on it.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ side: THREE.DoubleSide });

material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://i.imgur.com/ZjBRB2d.jpg');
material.bumpMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://i.imgur.com/tz483el.jpg');
```

[code](https://jsfiddle.net/arunjayakumar07/mmjLt9qa/)

Is Repeat Wrapping of bumpmaps are possible as maps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MeshLambertMaterial` does not support bump maps. Try `MeshPhongMaterial` or `MeshStandardMaterial`.

Bump maps support repeat wrapping, but as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886337/repeating-a-bump-map/14887087#14887087) if you have a diffuse map, too, the map and bump map must have the same repeat setting.

This limitation may be changed in a future release.

three.js r.77

Comment: out of the question .. How can i implement cloth visualisation in an effective way .

Comment: I recommend you study the [three.js cloth animation example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html).

Comment: I updated the material to `MeshPhongMaterial `, still there is no change , i tried adding normal map too, which also giving same result, but `MeshStandardMaterial` works :)

Comment: `MeshPhongMaterial` supports both normal maps and bump maps.