# Can't alter offset/repeat of texture used as alphaMap

Tags: javascript, three.js

demo:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/123374/so-pages/20160601/index.html

the `alphaTexture` is having it's offset altered during each render. as a "map" property it changes, but as an "alphaMap" it does not change. the 2nd mesh's alphaMap

relevant code from demo link:

```
var colorTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('blue.png')
  , alphaTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('alpha.png')
  , offset = 0
  , colorFill = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.Geometry(),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map:      colorTexture,
            alphaMap: alphaTexture,
            side:     THREE.DoubleSide,
            shading:  THREE.FlatShading
        })
    )

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render)

    offset += .01
    alphaTexture.offset.x = Math.sin(offset)
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

render()
```

**expected:**

the transparent part of the object would shift as the offset of the alphaTexture changes.

**actual:**

transparent part stays fixed on the material. However, if I edit the offset of the texture set to the `map` property (instead of `alphaMap`) it * is * able to shift, which seems like inconsistent behavior to me.

Comment: this might be related? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/8278

Comment: If you are not getting help, improve your question by making a simpler example with a single mesh and a single material. It is not clear what you expect to see.

Comment: @WestLangley thanks, I trimmed it down a bit and added expected vs actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a current "feature" of three.js: only one `offset/repeat` pair is allowed per mesh. `mesh.map` has priority.

For more info, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14372235/1461008

This may be changed in the future to allow separate `offset/repeat` settings per texture or per material property.

three.js r.84

Comment: thanks. Is there a work-around that I could look into? or a dev branch i could use?

Comment: Not yet. You can write your own `ShaderMaterial`, or update the `alphaMap` itself if updates are infrequent -- or hack the library.

Comment: thanks! i'm gonna try to hack the lib. sounds easier than writing a shader. i'm going to start with where materials are instantiated and work my way down, if there is a better starting point let me know.. thank you!

Comment: Comment out offset/repeat in `uv_vertex.glsl` and hardwire offset/repeat in `alphamap_fragment.glsl`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried commenting out the USE_ALPHAMAP with the latest version(82) but it didn't work. However, changing the vUv to vUv2 in the alpha_fragment chunk worked.

Jim

Comment: could you give more details of how it was done?